# Bash script - too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell

Why doesn't the following work? All I'm trying to do is execute a `adb` command and, if the response contains a certain string, then doing something about it.

I keep getting an error `[; too many arguments`

```
VARIABLE=$(adb devices);
if [ "$VARIABLE" == *list of attached* ]; then
  echo "adb command worked";
fi
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On another note: the command `adb devices` returns words `List of devices attached`, not `list of attached`. So your `if` statement may always return false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try quoting the arguments inside `[[ and ]]`:

```
VARIABLE="$(adb devices)"
if [[ "$VARIABLE" == *"list of attached"* ]]; then
  echo "adb command worked";
fi
```

`==` needs single argument on either side. When you use `[ "$VARIABLE" == *list of attached* ]` then `*list` is the first argument after `==` and rest are considered extra arguments.

Comment: `adb devices` probably also returns a good exit code, in which case `if adb devices > /dev/null 2>&1; then ..` would be the correct way (but not the questioner's way) of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively try using BASH's binary operator `=~` to do regex matching:

```
VARIABLE="$(adb devices)"
if [[ $VARIABLE =~ list\ of\ attached ]]; then
    echo "adb command worked"
fi
```

Comment: Terminology hint: Wildcard characters are associated with _globbing patterns_ - which is the feature the OP uses. The `=~` operator is for _regular expression_-matching.

Comment: @mklement0 You are correct.  Updated post to avoid any confusion.