# Too much arguments with grep at if

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I was trying to look for `$allowtunnel` string at my file.

Based on: [How to test if string exists in file with Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell)

So now I've the following at my script:

```
allowtunnel="PermitTunnel"
if [ grep -Fxq $allowtunnel /etc/ssh/sshd_config ]; then
```

Since at execution time it says "too much arguments", I was looking and found this:

[Bash script - too many arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372113/bash-script-too-many-arguments)

So I change it to:

```
if [[ grep -Fxq $allowtunnel /etc/ssh/sshd_config ]]; then
```

But now, It delivers me the next one:

```
./script_install.sh: línea 242: se esperaba un operador binario condicional
./script_install.sh: línea 242: error sintáctico cerca de `-Fxq`
./script_install.sh: línea 242: `    if [[ grep -Fxq $allowtunnel /etc/ssh/sshd_config ]]; then`
```

Translated would be:

```
./script_install.sh: line 242: binary conditional operator was expected
./script_install.sh: line 242: syntax error near of `-Fxq`
./script_install.sh: line 242: `    if [[ grep -Fxq $allowtunnel /etc/ssh/sshd_config ]]; then`
```

So as I understand, It doesn't let me use a second `[]` because it expects another operator. That leaves me without knowing what to do.

I've also seen this one: [Too many arguments error in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253969/too-many-arguments-error-in-bash) , but since I'm not comparing something but waiting for the result of grep I get anything useful from this one.

Thanks for reading

Comment: read the manual, `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` are for completely different purposes.

Comment: The brackets aren't just syntax; they are commands in their own right.

Comment: I wold modify chepner's comment to remove "just".  `[` is *not* part of the shell grammar (but `[[` *is*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since grep returns an exit status depending if the record is found or not, you could write your if statement like:

```
if grep .....; then
```